# Controlling suicide burn landing location in a python simulation?

Tags: landing, lunar-landing, simulation, python, vertical-landing

I recently asked a question in stackoverflow about [Simulation of suicide burn in openai-gym's LunarLander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59589776/simulation-of-suicide-burn-in-openai-gyms-lunarlander/59729706#59729706). Sadly most of my assumptions about suicide burn implementaion were wrong but [the answer given to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59729706/996366) solved my problem and able to land the lander gracefully. But if you watch the lander simulation its currently lands on random locations and I want to land the lander between the two flags which is in the range `(-0.05,0.05)` of `x`, where `x` is the `x=state[0]`
[image].

I can control the lander using 4 actions (nothing,down, left,right) but in my stackoverflow post I did simulations only with 2 of 4 actions. How do I force land my lander between these coordinnates?

A second minor question is regarding this equation

> ```
>  alt_burn = (y * g + 0.5 * v*v) / (13.0 / env.lander.mass * 0.5)
> ```

Why is acceleration of the engines should not be defined as the current acceleration?

Answer (score 4):

> Why is acceleration of the engines should not be defined as the current acceleration?

`alt_burn` is not an acceleration. It is, I think, the altitude to start the suicide burn. I don't know why the other poster called it an acceleration. If part of an answer confuses you, it's usually a good idea to ask for clarification from the person who gave you the answer.

> I want to land the lander between the two flags

One approach is to estimate where you're going to land and then make a corrective maneuver if you don't like the answer.

To estimate your landing x position, first estimate how much time you have until touchdown. Your current altitude divided by your current vertical speed is not a very good estimate, because you're going to be accelerated by gravity and then decelerated by your suicide burn, but it might be a good enough estimate for our purposes.

Take your current x position, add your x speed multiplied by time-til-touchdown, and that's your estimated landing x position.

If that x is too far to the left, add a rightward input. If it's too far to the right, add a leftward input.

Comment: `I don't know why the other poster called it an acceleration` I believe he meant this part of `alt_burn` equation `(13.0 / env.lander.mass * 0.5)`